# Projective space, fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}P^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ continuous. Let $q:S^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ die quotient map.
>
> Show, that:
>
> If $g_{\ast}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x))$ is not trivial (therefore contains more than one element) for one $x\in X$, then it is not trivial for every $x\in X$.
>
> Under this assumption is $h(-y)=-h(y)$ for every $y\in S^2$, with $h:S^2\to S^2$ and $q\circ h=g\circ q$.

Hello, I want to solve this task.
For the second part, I already showed, that this function $h$ exists. Also a hint is given, that we should use, that $S^2$ is simply connected.

I want to show, that

> If $g_{\ast}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x))$ is not trivial (therefore contains more than one element) for one $x\in X$, then it is not trivial for every $x\in X$.

But I can not find, how $g_{\ast}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x))$ is defined.
It is $g_{\ast}: \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x)\to\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x)$, with $[w]\mapsto [g\circ w]$

$g_{\ast}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x))$ should just be the set of all elements in the image of $g_{\ast}$.

Now, let $x'\in X$ be the element with $g_{\ast}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x'))$ is not trivial. Therefore it contains at least two different paths.

How can I show, that this map is not trivial for every other $x\in X$?

Thanks in advance.